# How to auto-fit images into DataGridView Image column with fixed size in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that displays employee data, including their status represented by two 48x48 images (Status_Active and Status_Inactive). I want to display these images in a fixed size (e.g., 16x16 or 32x32) within the DataGridView Image column. However, the images always appear enlarged. I have tried setting the ImageLayout to Center but it didn't work as expected.

Currently, I am retrieving the list of employees from the database and adding each employee to the DataGridView along with their corresponding status icon. However, the status icons appear larger than the desired fixed size.

My approach:

```
        var employees = db.Employees.ToList();
        // Add a row for each employee
        foreach (var employee in employees)
        {
            using (Image statusIcon = employee.IsActive ? Resources.Status_Active : Resources.Status_Inactive)
            {
                string fullName = employee.LastName + ", " + employee.FirstName;
                dgvStatustableau.Rows.Add(fullName, statusIcon);
            }
        }`
```

EDIT:

Thanks to @IVSoftware who stated a correct solution. I was able to workaround by creating a new bitmap with a 16x16 rectangle for the icon.

```
   Bitmap resizedIcon = new Bitmap(16, 16);
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(resizedIcon))
                {
                    g.DrawImage(statusIcon, new Rectangle(0, 0, 16, 16));
                }
```

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing more of your code and the error detail, but have you tried using `.ActualHeight` / `.ActualWidth`?

Comment: That is the only code related to the resources and populating the named gridview, i will append the Exception to the question once there isn't too many edits pending. The source is System.Drawing.Common. Do you mean actual size to get or update the property?

Comment: You're passing a disposed Image to the DataGridView -- @ScottSolmer Wrong platform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention that you set the `ImageMode` to `Center` and you may want to use `Stretch` instead.

[image: screenshot]

I reproduced your post where two embedded 48 x 48 images are part of the class that represents a row in the bound data set and are coerced into a 32 x 32 display area:

```
class Employee : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Employee()
    {
        ensureImages();
        Image = _imageInactive;
    }

    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public Image Image
    {
        get => _image;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_image, value))
            {
                _image = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Image)));
            }
        }
    }
    Image _image = null;

    [Browsable(false)]
    public bool IsActive
    {
        get => _isActive;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_isActive, value))
            {
                _isActive = value;
                Image = _isActive ? _imageActive : _imageInactive;
            }
        }
    }
    bool _isActive = false;

    private void ensureImages()
    {
        if(_imageActive == null) 
        {
            var names = typeof(Employee).Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
            _imageActive = localImageFromResourceName(names.First(_=>_.Contains("active.png")));
            _imageInactive = localImageFromResourceName(names.First(_ => _.Contains("inactive.png")));

            Image localImageFromResourceName(string resource)
            {
                using (var stream = GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resource)!)
                {
                    return new Bitmap(stream);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private static Image _imageActive = null;
    private static Image _imageInactive = null;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

---

**Main Form**

The main form formats the `DataGridView` and does a mock for where the database would read the data (since the database isn't part of the question).

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dgvStatustableau.DataSource = Employees;
        dgvStatustableau.AllowUserToAddRows= false;

        #region F O R M A T    C O L U M N S
        Employees.Add(new Employee());
        DataGridViewColumn column;
        column = dgvStatustableau.Columns[nameof(Employee.FullName)];
        column.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;

        column = dgvStatustableau.Columns[nameof(Employee.Image)];
        column.HeaderText= string.Empty;
        column.Width = 32;
        // Use Stretch here
        ((DataGridViewImageColumn)column)
        .ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch;
        Employees.Clear();
        #endregion F O R M A T    C O L U M N S

        mockAddEmployees();
    }
    private BindingList<Employee> Employees { get; } = new BindingList<Employee>();

    private void mockAddEmployees()
    {
        Employees.Add(new Employee
        {
            FullName= "Lisa Smith",
            IsActive= true,
        });
        Employees.Add(new Employee
        {
            FullName= "Bob Jones",
            IsActive= false,
        });
        Employees.Add(new Employee
        {
            FullName= "Rene Montoya",
            IsActive= true,
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work this around by resizing the icons drawing a new Bitmap.

```
                    Bitmap resizedIcon = new Bitmap(16, 16);
                    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(resizedIcon))
                    {
                        g.DrawImage(statusIcon, new Rectangle(0, 0, 16, 16));
                    }
```

Comment: *creating a new Bitmap object with a size of 16x16 and draw the original image onto it

Answer (score 0):

The [DataGridViewImageColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewimagecolumn?view=windowsdesktop-7.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) has an [ImageLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewimagecolumn.imagelayout?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) property which supports Normal, Stretch and Zoom:

- Normal: The image is centered and displayed in its original size.
- Stretch: The image stretches or shrinks to fit the width and height of the cell.
- Zoom: The image uniformly enlarges or shrinks until it fills the width or height of the cell.

Based on your question, it looks like you are interested in Zoom. So just assign whatever image you want, then set the ImageLayout property of the column to Zoom.